# Need to merge two codes into one - Macro for time stamp

Tags: vba, excel, merge, timestamp

This is my first post. I looked on other posts, but I was unable to reconstruct working code, so I opted to submit my query here. Below is native code for timestamp.

I have four separate columns A,C,E,G where I will be adding employee names and wish to obtain a timestamp in offset columns B,D,F,H.

I need one combined code to capture this. Please help!

## Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Macro #1   
    Dim WorkRng As Range    
    Dim Rng As Range    
    Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer

    Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), Target)    
    xOffsetColumn = 1

    If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then    
        Application.EnableEvents = False    

        For Each Rng In WorkRng        
            If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then       
                Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
                Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
            Else
                Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents   
            End If
        Next
    
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of merging two separate timestamp codes, I added column range into

```
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A, C:C, E:E, G:G"), Target)
```

With this step, my query has been resolved.

Comment: Note that you can mark your own answer as solution, so others can see it was resolved.